# On reconciling different definitions of the $\nabla$ operator in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: analysis, tensors

**Note**: This questions was originally asked in [iMechanica](http://imechanica.org/node/16461).  The main confusion appears to be on whether Christoffel symbols should appear in the divergence of a field expressed in curvilinear coordinates or not.

---

As is known to all, the Laplace operator in cylindrical coordinates is defined as
$$
\nabla^{2}=\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial r^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}+\dfrac{1}{r^{2}}\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\phi^{2}}+\dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial z^{2}}
$$
From here we can see that the $\nabla$ operator has the form
$$
\nabla=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{1}},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{2}},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{3}}\right)^{T}
$$
rather than
$$
\nabla=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\phi},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^{T}.
$$
In the recent book ''Introduction to Metamaterials and Waves in Composites'' by Biswajit Banerjee, there are Christoffel symbols in the definition of divergence of tensors (see page 9), which implies the $\nabla$ is defined by
$$
\nabla=(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{1}},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{2}},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{x}_{3}})^{T}
$$

However, in the book ''Tensor Analysis'' (in Chinese, 2ed) by K. C. Huang et.al, they define
$$
\nabla=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\boldsymbol{g}^{i}
$$
(see Eq.(4.2.14) in the book), where $x^{i}$ are the curvilinear coordinates. Hence Christoffel symbols do not occur in definition of divergence of a tensor. (see Eq.(4.4.2;4.4.3)).

Obviously, the two definitions for $\nabla$ are by no means compatible. So what is wrong?

Comment: For the approach used in ''Introduction to Metamaterials and Waves in Composites'' see [Tensors in curvilinear coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates#Vector_and_tensor_calculus_in_three-dimensional_curvilinear_coordinates).

Comment: What is the meaning of $\partial/\partial \bar x_1$?  How is it distinct from $\partial/\partial r$ when using cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @Muphrid: I think they mean that for a a scalar field, the gradient operator has the form $\nabla = (\partial/\partial r, 1/r \, \partial/\partial\phi, \partial/\partial z) \equiv (\partial/\partial\bar{x}_1, \partial/\partial\bar{x}_2, \partial/\partial\bar{x}_3)$.